# Macro output seems unrecognized by \newline

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I'm trying to make a macro.  It works for the most part, except it has some weird behavior.  If I have the macro called within some text and then insert a `\newline`, it creates a newline before it outputs the macro text.  I would like the macro text to be inserted before the newline.

So, when I use the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,noindent]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\address}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\@address % Address is already defined
        \if\noexpand\@empty#1   % Argument is empty
            \@address\mbox{}
        \else % Argument is non-empty
            \def\@address{#1}
        \fi
    \else   % Address is not defined
        \if\noexpand\@empty#1   % Argument is empty
            \def\@address{}
        \else   % Argument is non-empty
            \def\@address{#1}
        \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\address{John Smith\\
         12345 Luggage Way\\
         Portland, OR, 97231}

\begin{document}

    Before \address \newline
    After

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image: Image of Latex Output: Before (newline) 12345 Luggage Way (newline) Portland, OR, 97231 After]

I would be expecting a after the address is finished printing and not before.

Interestingly, when I remove all text on that line except for the macro and the \newline, the LaTeX complains that there is no line to end.  Not sure why that is.

Comment: `\if\noexpand\@empty#1` is surely a wrong test for emptyness of `#1`.

Comment: It may be, but it was working...  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: No, it won't generally work. I added some suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
\address \newline
```

the token `\newline` is taken as the argument to `\address`. Since `\@address` has already been defined by calling `\address` in the preamble, the true branch in `\ifdefined\@address` is taken.

Now `\if\noexpand\@empty\newline` is tested. The `\if` conditional does complete expansion until finding nonexpandable tokens. So it expands `\noexpand`, which makes `\@empty` temporarily equivalent to `\relax`; then `\newline` is expanded; its standard definition is `\protect\newline•` (where `•` stands for a space in the name). In that situation, `\protect` is equivalent to `\relax` (it is during normal typesetting), so we have

```
\if\relax\relax\newline•
```

The test returns true. So `\newline•` is executed: it contains the actual code for getting a new line; `\@address\mbox{}` follows.

---

If a macro is defined to have an argument, it will *always* look for one: either the text between braces if a `{` follows, or the next token.

You should use a `\printaddress` macro instead of overloading `\address`.

Note also that `\if\noexpand\@empty#1` is not at all a test for emptiness of `#1`. Indeed, if by chance `#1` is really empty (call such as `\address{}`), your code would compare `\@empty` (made equivalent to `\relax`) with a space token (which follows `#1`), so returning *false*. If `#1` is not empty, the test will return true whenever the first token of `#1`, after full expansion, is not a character token.

A reliable test for emptiness is

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
```

---

As I said, I wouldn't overload `\address`, but if that's what you want, you need to *redefine* it not to have an argument. The first call will set the address, the subsequent ones will print it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\address}[1]{%
  % this is for the first call
  \def\@address{#1}%
  % subsequent calls will print the address
  \let\address\print@address
}
\newcommand{\@address}{}% initialize
\newcommand\print@address{\@address\mbox{}}
\makeatother

\address{John Smith\\
         12345 Luggage Way\\
         Portland, OR, 97231}

\begin{document}

Before \address \newline
After

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any explanation for a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

egreg already explained why the tests etc. fails.

Here is some code golfing with `xparse` and the `g` type which establishes an optional argument delimited by `{}` (actually, this is weird!). I prefer a traditional `o` type argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\addressweird}{+g}{%
  \@ifundefined{@addressweird}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \def\@addressweird{#1}%
    }{%
      \def\@addressweird{}%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \def\@addressweird{#1}%
    }{%
      \@addressweird\mbox{}%
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\address}{+o}{%
  \@ifundefined{@address}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \def\@address{#1}%
    }{%
      \def\@address{}%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \def\@address{#1}%
    }{%
      \@address\mbox{}%
    }%
  }%
}



\title{Hello}

\makeatother

\addressweird{John Smith\\
         12345 Luggage Way\\
         Portland, OR, 97231
       }


\address[Gandalf The Gray\\
         Moria\\
         Middle of Middle Earth
       ]


\begin{document}
    Before \address \newline
    After

    \address

    Before \addressweird \newline After
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `g` arguments.

Comment: @egreg: That's why I wrote `weird`. I would not use it for personal purposes neither! Perhaps traditional `o` is better.